# Change browser to display retina or webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2

Tags: css, web-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to simulate a retina display (HiDPI mode) in Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion on a non-retina display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124576/how-to-simulate-a-retina-display-hidpi-mode-in-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-on)

Is it possible to test my app in a browser, and have the browser pretend to be retina?

I want to test a web app, and check how it would look on an iPad, that has a retina display.

Comment: Could perhaps this be of any help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124576/how-to-simulate-a-retina-display-hidpi-mode-in-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-on

Comment: perfect, could not find it,thanks.