# iOS 6 simulator doesn't look like iPhone

Tags: ios6

My iOS iPhone simulator quit looking like an iPhone for some reason.  Now it looks more like an iPad.  Just yesterday it looked like an iPhone4/5 depending on my device selection.

Here is an example of the odd look: http://cl.ly/KUZ2
[image]

Anyone know how to get it to look like an iPhone again?  I want this for capturing demo shots.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have observed that the simulator will show this view if it is launched on a non-Retina screen. If I run the same app & same simulator on a retina screen, it will show the actual iPhone 4/5 frame.

If you do not have a Retina MBP, you might try enabling HiDPI mode on your Mac and then restarting the simulator. But I don't know for sure if this will work. See: [How to simulate a retina display (HiDPI mode) on a non-retina display?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12124577/462264)