# Labels do not appear in Mac Retina devices

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocos2d-iphone

I received couple of screenshots from a user indicating that the `CCMenuItemFont` and `CCLabelTTF` do not appear on a Macbook retina device. All the images in the application are correctly shown while the text doesn't appear correctly.

A code sample of one of the labels:

```
    CCLabelTTF *label=[CCLabelTTF labelWithString:answer fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:30];
    [label setColor:ccc3(255, 255, 255)];
    [label setPosition:ANSWER_POSITION];
    [self addChild:label];
```

I am using two languages in the application. The english words appear as a small wave while the others don't appear at all. A screenshot to show an english word:
[image: Incorrectly displayed label]

Unfortunately, I don't have access to a Retina device, and the following method is not working for me to debug the problem: [How to simulate a retina display (HiDPI mode) in Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion on a non-retina display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124576/how-to-simulate-a-retina-display-hidpi-mode-in-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-on)

Any ideas how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in the version of cocos2d that I was using (2.0V). Either use 2.1 or apply the solution mentioned in this link:
[Solution](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/36096)

The solution that worked correctly for both languages was adding the following line in CCTexture2D:

```
[[NSAffineTransform transform] set];
```