# Does cocos2diphone support retina graphics in Mac apps?

Tags: macos, cocos2d-iphone, retina-display

Does cocos2diphone support retina graphics in Mac apps?

If so, how do I enable it, and can I confirm someway that the retina graphics are enabled?

Using the way described by Apple maybe does not work (it doesn't for me). Described here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/HighResolutionOSX.pdf

Note: I am using retina in simulated mode as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13596261/129202 I don't have a retina Mac :-(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that cocos2diphone for mac does not enable retina support fully (yet, or something) with 2.1:

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop-v2/cocos2d/CCConfiguration.m

This says it all:

```
// XXX: Add here support for Mac Retina Display
ret = kCCDeviceMac;
```

kCCDeviceMac is 1x mode. Trying 2x mode (kCCDeviceMacRetinaDisplay) indeed loads high res graphics but the scale is incorrect. Or it just isn't working with simulated retina display. I'll need to confirm this with a real retina device :-(