# Is this possible to simulate an retina display OS X on non retina display Mac?

Tags: macos, swift, retina-display

I am using an iMac to do OS X App Development, but my iMac is not a retina display. Is this possible to let me simulate the result on retina display Mac? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [Quartz Debug](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Testing/Testing.html) to get a `HiDPI` entry in Displays. This was pre-Mavericks, so I'm not sure if that's still the recommended way to do it.
[The answers here mention a couple different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124576/how-to-simulate-a-retina-display-hidpi-mode-in-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-on?rq=1).

You may also need to [hold <kbd>Option</kbd> while clicking on "Scaled" in Displays](http://embraceware.com/blog/2013/07/test-retina-graphics-hidpi-on-a-non-retina-display/).