# Is there a way to simulate a non-retina mac?

Tags: retina-display, osx-elcapitan, simulate

On a retina display mac, how can I run an application or the entire OS in a non-retina mode?

What I have done:

I have checked this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124576/how-to-simulate-a-retina-display-hidpi-mode-in-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-on) [and this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872623/is-this-possible-to-simulate-an-retina-display-os-x-on-non-retina-display-mac)and [apple startup buttons](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201255)
I have done many searches leading to dead ends.

What I want:

To run my app to compare differences in rendering quality between retina and non-retina machines.

I thought maybe there is some keystroke when I launch, or some system setting, but I might not know what the term is for this toggle.

Comment: VMware Fusion has a setting which controls whether a VM sees the full retina resolution or not, so you probably could set up a Mac OS X VM with retina resolution disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do Get Info on an app, you can click the checkbox for "Open in Low Resolution":

[image: Espresso]